# How to perform queries with large $in data set in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, optimization

I have simple query like this: `{"field": {$nin: ["value1","value2","valueN"]}}`.

The problem is large amount of unique values to exclude (using `$nin` operator). It's about 50000 unique values to filter and about 1Kb of query length.

**Question**: *Is there elegant and performant way to do such operations?*

**Example**.
Collection `daily_stat` with **56M** of docs. Each day increases collection with 100K docs. Example of document

```js
{
    "day": "2020-04-15",
    "username": "uniq_name",
    "total": 12345
}
```

I run next query:

```
{
  "date": "2020-04-15",
  "username": {
    $nin: [
      "name1",
      "name2",
      "...",
      "name50000"
    ]
  }
}
```

MongoDB version: 3.6.12

Comment: So you wanted to pass in 50k values in input query & get docs which doesn't have these ? Can you elaborate a bit more - like how your data looks like & what functionality you're trying to achieve..

Comment: Exactly. Pass in 50k values in input query. I am not sure I can give more details as functionality as simple as described. Let it be the task where I need to exclude 50k banned ips from my collection

Comment: Seems like your approach *is* the elegant one.   You have 50K things to exclude which you can package into an array 50K long.   As long as the query itself is under 16M in size  and you have an index on `field` then you should be OK.   I just tried this on a collection of 10m docs and it takes MUCH longer to extract the 9.95m records that are NOT part of the exclude.

Comment: Query length is not an issue; you can define an array variable and use within the query. How many documents are there in the collection? What is the MongoDB version? Do you have an index on the query's filter field? Are there any other query conditions along with the one you had specified? Did you generate a _query plan_ using the `explain("executionStats")`? Please share these info.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Actually I don't have performance issues currently. I am looking for elegant way of doing such operations. Query takes 200 millis to finish, its ok for me now. But I can guess gradual performance degradation with the grow of items to exclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the big `$nin` array is the elegant solution.  If there is an index on `field` then it will also be performant -- but only in terms of quickly excluding those docs not to be returned in the cursor.   If you have, say, 10 million docs in a collection and you do a `find()` to exclude 50000, you are still dragging 9,950,000 records out of the DB and across the wire; that is non-trivial.

Comment: Want to clarify this once again
>  but only in terms of quickly excluding those docs
Could you provide example what does it mean? 
I am about to update my question to add more details

Comment: The more records that you want to return as a percentage of the total size of the collection, then performance is less determined by DB indexes and speed and more on the network.   Extreme example: Exclude 5 things from 10m.   You don't even need a DB.   Other extreme:  *ONLY* fetch 5 things from 10m.  Now you DEF want an index.

Comment: ahh, as simple as is. I was only concerned about mongo server performance parsing and handling large queries. I accept your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you can find a pattern in the values you pass in you can try with regex. Example given below

```
db.persons.find({'field':{$nin:[/san/i]}},{_id:0,"field":1})
```

more details on regex in

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: good point, but I have all the unique values, so there can't be pattern to match